# dockerfile is not creating directory and copying files?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following in my dockerfile. (There is much more. but I have pasted the relevant part here)

```
RUN useradd jenkins
USER jenkins

# Maven settings
RUN mkdir ~/.m2
COPY settings.xml ~/.m2/settings.xml
```

The docker build goes through fine and when I run docker image, I see NO errors.

but I do not see `.m2` directory created at `/home/jenkins/.m2` in the host filesystem.

I also tried replacing `~` with `/home/jenkins` and still I do not see `.m2` being created.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something similar and got

```
Step 4 : RUN mkdir ~/.m2
 ---> Running in 9216915b2463
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/jenkins/.m2': No such file or directory
```

your useradd is not enough to create /home/jenkins

I do for my user gg

```
RUN useradd -d /home/gg -m -s /bin/bash gg
RUN echo gg:gg | chpasswd
RUN echo 'gg ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/gg
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/gg
USER gg
ENV HOME /home/gg
WORKDIR /home/gg
```

This creates the directory of the user gg
`

Comment: why line 2,3,4 are necessary.

Comment: not sure they are absolutely necessary, but the first one is

Comment: when I make the change, I see the permission of -rw------- for the newly created .m2/settings.xml. but it should be read/write for jenkins user for entire .m2 directory correct?

Comment: I tried to change permission my self for the new created file, but I get error `RUN mkdir .m2
COPY settings.xml .m2/settings.xml
RUN chmod -R 755 .m2`. I get the following error `chmod: changing permissions of '.m2/settings.xml': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Do you have a link to your whole Dockerfile?

Comment: I wish I could share it. but I can't. can you try copying some text file in the created directory and check the permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100195/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-user2915097).